# Django class based views, is this right approach?

Tags: django

I am using django with django-braces. This is to ask for an opinion if this is the right approach.

For this example I am just trying to return Users and a particular user in json format using CBV.

Views

```
class ListAllUsers(JSONResponseMixin, DetailView):

    model = User
    json_dumps_kwargs = {u"indent": 2}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        object = self.get_object()
        context_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
        if not self.kwargs.get("pk"):
            for obj in object:
                context_dict[obj.id].append ({
                    u"name": obj.username,
                    u"email": obj.email
                })
        else:
            context_dict[object.id].append ({
                u"name": object.username,
                u"email": object.email

            })
        return self.render_json_response(context_dict)

    def get_object(self):
        if not self.kwargs.get("pk"):
            return User.objects.all()
        else:
            return get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.kwargs.get("pk"))
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^users/$', ListAllUsers.as_view(), name="users-list"),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', ListAllUsers.as_view(), name="users-detail")
]
```

I know it's a subjective question but I want your opinions please be supportive because I am having a hard time figuring out how to use CBVs optimally.

Comment: Maybe try asking on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually using a function-based view within a `DetailView` class based view (the `if` statement is the function determining whether to return one object or all the objects). `DetailView` is a Django class based view for showing detail on one object. You should make this view do that one thing only.

To show a list of objects, you should use [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview).

One solution is to write a second `ListView` and call it from your urls.py rather than calling your `DetailView` for both of your url endpoints.

Comment: I would also suggest defining a common function `serialize_user()` to avoid duplicating code.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini yeah it's not clear what he's trying to do. If he's rendering HTML to a browser it makes most sense to simply pass the user object in a context dictionary rather than JSON. If he really is returning json as an endpoint for an API the best approach is django rest framework and use the class based views therein.

Comment: thanks Andrea and YP I will wait a couple of hours before accepting this answer just in case there is someone feeling helpful out there just like you two. :)